# Editing a Search Form

Tags: search, forms

I am working on a search form in my Wordpress site.

It has an advance search box in which there is an Advance button, clicking which drops custom filters to include. https://ibb.co/R7DFC1F >> I want to remove that Advance button while all the filters [Type, Province, Categories, and Price] below must remain fixed (without clicking anything). My staging website is here at http://f1stock.info/1

```
    <div class="iw-field iw-display-table-cell field-for-add-advanced">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="iw-search-add-advanced"><i class="ion-android-settings"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( "Advance", 'iwproperty' ) ?></span></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use a plugin to display this form. If you use a plugin and you can't modify plugin scripts, I advice you to use CSS. You can add this line to style.css of your theme (Go to Appearance > theme editor) :

```
.iw-search-add-advanced {display:none!important;} /*not display advance button */
.iw-fields-advanced {display:block!important;} /* display filters */
```